# Object details don't get passed into another object pointer [Python 3]

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x

I've been trying to write a simple code for breadth first search with uniform edges of cost 6, but when I call the neighbors of my second Vertex object (I am using an adjacency list) from the queue, an empty list is returned. Whereas if i call the same list anywhere else in the code, the proper list is returned. I have been trying to debug for a while, but to no avail.

Here is the code:

```
import queue
import math

#Vertex Class Definition
class Vertex:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name
        self.neighbors= []
        self.nay=[]

    def addneighbor(self, neigh):
        if not neigh in self.nay:
            self.nay.append(neigh)
            self.neighbors.append(Vertex(neigh))

    def getneigh(self):
        return self.neighbors

    def getname(self):
        return int(self.name)

#Graph Class definition
class Graph:
    def __init__(self):
        self.verts=[]
        self.num= 0

    def addvert(self, node):
        self.verts.append(Vertex(node))

    def addedge(self, fro, to):
        self.verts[fro-1].addneighbor(to)  
        self.verts[to-1].addneighbor(fro)

def bfs(g,s):

    q= queue.Queue(maxsize=0)
    q.put(g.verts[s-1])
    cost= [-1 for yy in range(g.num)]
    cost[s-1]=0

    while(not q.empty()):

        p=q.get()



'''If I check for p.getneigh() here, only the neigbors of 
source element s are returned. Otherwise, the loop stops
after calling the first neighbor of s. However, if I 
explicitly call g.verts and check for neigbors, the list 
is complete.'''

        for vex in p.getneigh():
            if cost[vex.name-1]==-1:
                q.put(vex)
                cost[vex.name-1]= cost [p.name-1]+6

    return cost

t= 1     
for hehe in range (t):
    n, e= 10, 6

    g= Graph()
    #add n vertices
    for i in range (1, n+1):
        g.addvert(i)
        g.num+=1
    arr= [ [3, 1], [10, 1], [10, 1] , [3, 1] , [1, 8], [5, 2]]
    for i in range(e):
        x,y = arr[i][0], arr[i][1]
        g.addedge(x, y)

    s= 3
    #s is the start node of the graph
    c=bfs(g,s)

    del c[s-1] 

    for yoy in c:
        stdout.write(str(yoy))
        stdout.write(" ") 
    stdout.write("\n")
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the setup, the graph should look like this:

```
       3  5   6  4 7 8 9
      /    \
10 - 1      2
     |
     8
```

The problem is not with queue, your graph is incorrect, here is the test code to show this:

```
t= 1     
for hehe in range (t):
    n, e= 10, 6

    g= Graph()
    # ...
    # ...
    s= 3
    print('g.verts[s-1] is ', g.verts[s-1].getname())
    print('g.verts[s-1] neigh ', g.verts[s-1].getneigh()[0].getname())
    print('g.verts[s-1] neigh[0] -> neigh', g.verts[s-1].getneigh()[0].getneigh())
    print('------------')

    #s is the start node of the graph
    c=bfs(g,s)
    # ...
```

The output:

```
g.verts[s-1] is  3
g.verts[s-1] neigh  1
g.verts[s-1] neigh[0] -> neigh []
```

You can see that even before we go into the `bfs` function and use queue, the vertex `3` has a neighbor `1`, but vertex `1` has no neighbors.
While it should have `3`, `10` and `8` according to the setup.

The problem is here:

```
def addedge(self, fro, to):
    self.verts[fro-1].addneighbor(to)
    self.verts[to-1].addneighbor(fro)
```

The `self.verts[fro-1]` is a `Vertex` object, but `to` is an integer (you pass integers into `addedge`).
So instead of connecting two vertices with each other, you create new vertex each time (inside the `Vertex.addneighbor`), so you end up with `3` -> `1` -> [] for vertex `3`. And there will be a also another copy of the vertex `1` in the graph which will have `3`, `8` and `10` neighbours and `3` will be not the same as known for the graph.

Below is a corrected code, hidden under the spoiler, so you can try to fix the issue by yourself.

Hint: `self.verts[fro-1].addneighbor(self.verts[to-1])`.

```js
from sys import stdin, stdout
import queue
import math
from collections import OrderedDict

#Vertex Class Definition
class Vertex:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = int(name)
        self.neighbors = OrderedDict()

    def add_neighbor(self, neigh):
        assert(isinstance(neigh, Vertex))
        if neigh.get_name() not in self.neighbors:
            self.neighbors[neigh.get_name()] = neigh

    def get_neighbours(self):
        return list(self.neighbors.values())

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    def get_neighbours_names(self):
        return [n.get_name() for n in self.get_neighbours()]


#Graph Class definition
class Graph:
    def __init__(self):
        self.verts = []
        self.num = 0

    def add_vert(self, node):
        self.verts.append(Vertex(node))

    def add_edge(self, fro, to):
        print('%s -> %s' % (fro, to))
        self.verts[fro-1].add_neighbor(self.verts[to-1])
        self.verts[to-1].add_neighbor(self.verts[fro-1])

def bfs(g,s):

    q= queue.Queue(maxsize=0)
    q.put(g.verts[s-1])
    cost= [-1 for yy in range(g.num)]
    cost[s-1]=0

    print('g.verts[s-1] is ', g.verts[s-1].get_name())
    print('g.verts[s-1] neigh ', g.verts[s-1].get_neighbours_names())
    print('g.verts[s-1] neigh[0] -> neigh', g.verts[s-1].get_neighbours()[0].get_neighbours_names())
    print('------------')

    while(not q.empty()):

        p=q.get()

        """If I check for p.get_neighbours() here, only the neigbors of
        source element s are returned. Otherwise, the loop stops
        after calling the first neighbor of s. However, if I
        explicitly call g.verts and check for neighbors, the list
        is complete."""

        print('p is ', p)
        print('p name is ', p.get_name())
        print('p nei ', p.get_neighbours_names())
        if len(p.get_neighbours()) > 0:
            print('p nei -> nei ', p.get_neighbours()[0].get_neighbours_names())
        print('------------')

        for vex in p.get_neighbours():
            if cost[vex.name-1]==-1:
                q.put(vex)
                cost[vex.name-1]= cost [p.name-1]+6

    return cost

t= 1
for hehe in range (t):
    n, e= 10, 6

    g= Graph()
    #add n vertices
    for i in range (1, n+1):
        g.add_vert(i)
        g.num+=1
    arr= [ [3, 1], [10, 1], [10, 1] , [3, 1] , [1, 8], [5, 2]]
    for i in range(e):
        x,y = arr[i][0], arr[i][1]
        g.add_edge(x, y)

    s= 3
    #s is the start node of the graph
    c=bfs(g,3)

    c=bfs(g,1)

    del c[s-1]

    for yoy in c:
        stdout.write(str(yoy))
        stdout.write(" ")
    stdout.write("\n")

"""
       3  5   6  4 7 8 9
      /    \
10 - 1      2
     |
     8
"""
```

Comment: The source vertex's neighbors are being returned  but the neighbours of the next neighbor of source is always an empty list. For example for the pairs (1,3)(2,3)(3,4), with 1 as source, I would get 3 as 1s neighbor but when checking the neighbors of 3,an empty list is returned.

Comment: @SaumitraBose it would be good if you update the code in your question with the reproducible example which does not require manual input, something like my code above, you can just run it and see the result, no need to guess what values to enter.

Comment: @SaumitraBose I updated my answer, the problem is not with Queue, but with the graph itself. Also thanks for the code update, just a notice - it would be even better if you include the problem highlight also in the code (not as text), something like print statements I had in my answer. The code to show what exactly is wrong, it is a lot easier to run the code and see the problem right away.

Comment: @SaumitraBose did my answer help to solve the problem?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Thank you, I never would've caught it without your help! It works perfectly fine now. Will update the question as per your suggestions.

Comment: @SaumitraBose I am glad it helped and no need to update this question, just use the approach I suggested for future questions you may have and you'll get more attention, check also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).